# Joomla! 2.5: set value into protected variable

Tags: php, session, joomla

i am trying to set a new variable into the protected object 'data' within a JRegistry object (within the $_SESSION variable):

```
["registry"]=> object(JRegistry)#22 (1) { 

    ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#23 (3) {

        ["users"]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) { 
            …
        } 
        // here is my new variable supposed to be
    }
}
```

I tried using

`JRegistry::set($_SESSION['__default']['registry']->data, $test);`

and

`JRegistry::setValue($_SESSION['__default']['registry']->data, $test);`,

but both ways evoke the error message "Cannot access protected property JRegistry::$data". 
Is there a way to write INTO this protected variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `JRegistry` calls incorrectly, you don't pass the global variable $_SESSION in.

The signature for the `set()` and `setValue()` calls are:

```
public function set($path, $value)
```

and

```
public function setValue($path, $value)
```

**N.B.** *Please note that `setValue()` is deprecated.*

Once you have your `JRegistry` object you set values by passing the `$path` attribute (e.g. Registry Path e.g. **'joomla.content.showauthor'**) and the value.